# C# Console.Readkey - wait for specific input

Tags: c#, console, keypress

I have a small C# console app I am writing.

I would like the app to wait for instruction from the user regarding either a Y or a N keypress (if any other key is pressed the app ignores this and waits for either a Y or a N and then runs code dependent on the Y or N answer.

I came up with this idea,

```
while (true)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo result = Console.ReadKey();
    if ((result.KeyChar == "Y") || (result.KeyChar == "y"))
    {
         Console.WriteLine("I'll now do stuff.");
         break;
    }
    else if ((result.KeyChar == "N") || (result.KeyChar == "n"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I wont do anything");
        break;
    }
}
```

Sadly though VS says its doesnt like the result.Keychat == as the operand cant be applied to a 'char' or 'string'

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: single quote, not double ... (result.KeyChar == 'Y') || (result.KeyChar == 'y')

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`KeyChar` is a `char` while `"Y"` is a `string`.

You want something like `KeyChar == 'Y'` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. A schoolboy error on my part. Still struggling with C# after the php move! Thanks again.

Comment: An alternative would be this: `result.Key == ConsoleKey.Y`

Comment: @K_Rol: That might work. I'd be concerned that it would accept not just `Y` and `Shift+Y`, but also `Ctrl+Y`.

Comment: You are right, I just tested it and it does accept Shift+Y (or any combination).

Answer (score 5):

Check this instead

```
string result = Console.ReadLine();
```

And after check the result

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```cs
void PlayAgain()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? Y/N: ");
    string result = Console.ReadLine();
    if (result.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || result.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Start();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the user to confirm their response by pressing enter, so ReadLine is best. Also convert the string response to upper case for generic comparison check. Like so:

```
string result = Console.ReadLine();
if (result.ToUpper().Equals("Y"))
{
    // Do what ya do ...
```